# Does Skype status ever automatically change to Offline?

Tags: skype

Can Skype go into "offline" status when the computer shuts down via sleep mode?  If this is possible, can it awaken into "online" mode by a click of the mouse or keyboard?

Comment: Which Skype app and version are you using and on which OS? (Additionally, if you're on Windows 8, are you using the Skype Desktop or Metro version?)